# How to use top with only showing CMD name

Tags: top

How do you use `top` with just showing the CMD name?

I have used `top` with just showing the running process that I want; for example:

```
$ top -p 19745
```

And if I want more than one PID, I would use:

```
$ top -p 19745 -p 19746 -p 19747
```

I have Googled it, but they don't say how you can do it, even when I try looking at the help in `top` it still doesn't show you.

Is there a way you can filter by the CMD name only?

There are certain files that I am running through Apache2, and I want to monitor them only.

```
afile1.abc
afile2.abc
afile3.abc
afile4.abc
```

**Update**

I see this in the `man top` page:

```
x: Command  --  Command line or Program name
      Display the command line used to start a task or the name of the associated
      program.   You toggle between command line and name with 'c', which is both
      a command-line option and an interactive command.

      When you've chosen to display command lines, processes  without  a  command
      line  (like  kernel  threads)  will  be shown with only the program name in
      parentheses, as in this example:
            ( mdrecoveryd )

      Either form of display is subject to potential truncation if it's too  long
      to fit in this field's current width.  That width depends upon other fields
      selected, their order and the current screen width.

      Note: The 'Command' field/column is unique, in that it is not  fixed-width.
      When  displayed,  this  column will be allocated all remaining screen width
      (up to the maximum 512 characters) to provide for the potential  growth  of
      program names into command lines.
```

Will that do anything for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `top` supports filtering, start `top` then type the following interactive command:

```
oCOMMAND=afile
```

The field name, `COMMAND`, must be all uppercase.

From the man page:

```
5e. FILTERING in a Window
   You can use the 'Other Filter' feature to establish selection cri‐
   teria which will then determine which tasks are shown in the ´cur‐
   rent´ window.

   Establishing a filter requires: 1) a field name; 2)  an  operator;
   and  3) a selection value, as a minimum.

   Filter Basics
      .  field names are case sensitive and spelled as in the header
      .  selection values need not comprise the full displayed field
      .  separate unique filters are maintained for each task window

Keyboard Summary
     o  :Other-Filter (lower case)
         You will be prompted to establish a filter that ignores case
         when matching.

     O  :Other-Filter (upper case)
         You will be prompted to establish a case sensitive filter.
```

Comment: Should I use this command line: `top oCOMMAND=afile`? I tried that and got: `top: unknown argument 'o'`

Comment: The `o` command is an interactive command only, as far as I can tell. Start `top` first, then type it.

Comment: Oops, I moved the `X: COMMAND` to the top of the filters list. It is now in the front of the list. But I can't filter it by only that one filename: `afile`

Comment: I have used `top -i` and have all the running processes, which is sufficient for me, as I have this machine on VirtualBox.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you could do something like below as suggested [here](https://serverfault.com/a/343878).

```
top -p `pgrep -d ',' "apache2"`
```

I believe the comma delimiter is not needed in this case as we have only one process.

```
top -p `pgrep "apache2"`
```

Comment: Sorry, I edited my post, saying: "There is a certain file that I am running through Apache2, and I want to monitor it only." - I can sort them alphabetically by pressing `c`, but that doesn't really help... Well it does for me, as the filename starts with "A"

Comment: @Kevdog777, please see the updates.

Comment: Oh wait, it disappears when it refreshes itself.

Comment: @Kevdog777, I believe the comma delimiter is not needed in `pgrep`. Can you try the updated command?

Comment: I am getting this: `top: unknown argument '1'`

Comment: See I can do this: `top -p `pgrep -d ',' "afile*"`` but then shows the first 3, then disappears... When I try the other command, you gave, I get this: `top: unknown argument '7'
usage:  top -hv | -bcisSH -d delay -n iterations [-u user | -U user] -p pid [,pid ...]`

Comment: I am using `Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS`, if that makes any difference?

Comment: It sounds like these processes come and go every few seconds and the OP would like to see them even when they are created after `top` has already started. @Kevdog777, is that correct?

Comment: Well they are running all the time, but they might drop off every so often - but, yes that is correct. I really want to see them, even if they are `sleeping`.

Comment: It looks like the PID's are changing, so maybe it is what you say then @MarkPlotnick, cuz when the PID changes, it means it has died and started again, gaining a new PID.