# How to view a specific process in top

Tags: process, top

Are there any relatively strightforward options with top to track a specific process?
Ideally by identifying the process by a human readable value? e.g. `chrome` or `java`.

In other words, I want to view all the typical information top provides, but for the results to be filtered to the parameters provided i.e.. 'chrome' or 'java'

Comment: have you tried `top | grep chrome`?

Comment: you can also use `ps -x | chrome` to get pid (let pid shown `2034`) and then `top | grep 2034`

Comment: `top | grep chrome` worked perfectly - thanks!

Comment: @Pandya - also, the process I was looking for only ran for a few seconds (node.js during an integration test) - which meant when I used `ps -x | process_name` to get the PID, when I ran the process again the PID was different and therefore the original PID wouldn't identify it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You can simply use **`grep`**:

```
NAME
       grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep - print lines matching a pattern

SYNOPSIS
       grep [OPTIONS] PATTERN [FILE...]
       grep [OPTIONS] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]

DESCRIPTION
       grep  searches  the  named  input  FILEs (or standard input if no files are named, or if a single
       hyphen-minus (-) is given as file name) for lines containing a match to the  given  PATTERN.   By
       default, grep prints the matching lines.
```

Run following command to get output which you want (ex-chrome):

```
top | grep chrome
```

Here we are using `grep` with pipelines `|` so `top` & `grep` run parallel ; `top` output given to `grep` (as input) and `grep chrome` filters matching lines `chrome` until `top` stopped.

Comment: thanks, I know other people have their preferences, but I like this answer because it is easy to understand, and therefore its easier to remember in the future too! - I would have upvoted but I dont have enough reputation...

Comment: This only works if the process is in top's displayed output. I think @Ramesh's answer should be the accepted one

Comment: @JamieBullock the question deals with `top` only and OP want to filter process based on `top`.

Comment: @Pandya actually, I withdraw my previous comment as it was based on a mistake in my code. Still I think @Ramesh's answer is better (and also filters process based on top). I can easily break yours e.g. with `sleep 10 & top | grep sleep`

Comment: I like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165343/48973 better because it shows the headers.

Comment: If I press 1 after top it shows individual core utilization info, but not when I grep a process. Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: @jb is correct. this technique fails if the process of interest does not fall within the small subset of processes displayed on the terminal, for instance if you have a small terminal or the process sorts very low on the list.

Answer (score 88):

From my other answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/147447/47538), you could do something like,

```
top -p `pgrep "java"`
```

Comment: `top -p \`pgrep "java"\`` gives me the following error in a bash shell `top: -p requires argument` . **top -p `pgrep -d ',' "apache2"`** did work for me, but I didn't really understand what the command was doing - is it way of feeding in multiple arguments to top?

Comment: @Ramesh you need to give the `pid` list comma separated to work.

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer. "top | grep Chrome" is rather barbaric, because it greps-away ALL OF THE OUTPUT from top not matching "Chrome," losing stuff like the header and column labels. Using a subshell with the output from pgrep is a correct application of the unix philosophy.

Comment: for some reason it works when using certain running commands, but for other it is not.

Comment: @loretoparisi that may be because the selector you are using matches multiple processes. See [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/347544/243709) for a command that works with one or more matching processes.

Comment: This solution fails in a situation where short-term java processes come and go - e.g. batch jobs. This solution only matches against processes running at the time the command is issued.

Comment: When I run this I get "top: -p requires argument"

Comment: **`top: -p requires argument`** means that there is not found any process with specified name. The `pgrep` returns empty string.

Comment: Getting `top: invalid option -- 'p'`

Answer (score 54):

```
top -p `pgrep -d "," java`
```

Explanation:

1. `top -p pid1,pid2`: show multiple process information, the pid should be separated by `,`
2. `pgrep -d "," java`: print the pids of all java program, the pids are separated by a newline by default. use the `-d ","` to separate it by `,` as required by the top.

If you see error like `top: -p argument missing`, it means no java program is running, i.e. the pgrep has no output.

Comment: This solution works better than using `top -p `pgrep "java"`` only. thank you.

Comment: Prevent the error by checking `pgrep`'s exit code : `pids="$(pgrep -d, java)" && top -p "$pids"`

Comment: This solution does not "update" because pgrep is only evaluated once. See @Kusalananda's answer which uses top filtering.

Comment: Incidentally, the top option on the default system top on macOS is `-pid` (for anyone finding themselves here for this answer).

Answer (score 44):

In OpenBSD `top`, just press <kbd>g</kbd> and enter the command name you'd like to filter on.

In `top` on e.g. Ubuntu, press <kbd>o</kbd> and enter e.g. `COMMAND=chrome` to only show entries from the `COMMAND` column that are equal to `chrome`.

On Linuxes that uses the same `top` implementation as Ubuntu, read the *FILTERING in a Window* section in the `top` manual.

Comment: This answer has the benefit of updating if a new process begins after calling top!

Comment: It is indeed a nice answer, but I would add that you should just type "=" (without quotation marks) if you want to get rid of filters and enter a new one. If you just enter a new one without deleting the old one, then both will apply, which may or may not be what you intend.

Comment: After filtering a specific process using `o` key and entering `COMMAND=ssh` how can we go back and see the full list again?

Comment: We can press `=` this will clear all filters.

Answer (score 8):

Other good answers have been provided, but I made a script some time ago, which I named ptop, that serves me well:

```
#!/bin/sh
top -p $(pidof "$@" |sed s#\ #,#g) 2>/dev/null
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo No processes with the specified name\(s\) were found
fi
```

This supports multiple process names to be specified (like `ptop bash chrome`) and provides a nicer error message in case there is/are no processes with any of the specified names running.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to stay in `top` and keep all other processes in view for context, you can press `L` to search for your process:

```
Locate string chrome
```

This will highlight any process with `chrome` in the name, and bring it into view. Use `&` to go to the next match.

You can press `c` to switch between showing the process name and the full command.

Comment: This ^ because RTFM people! `man top | less +/5d`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use a filter in top to isolate specific processes. Press 'O' to bring up the filter prompt. Then type a filter formatted as FIELD=value. For example, to filter all tmux processes, use:

```
COMMAND=tmux
```

Use '=' to reset filters. See the section titled 'FILTERING' in the top man page.

Answer (score 5):

On a Linux terminal:

Type:

```
top
```

Then hit the <kbd>o</kbd> key, this will prompt you to add a filter.
You can then apply a filter to the "COMMAND" column, for example if you wanted to see the "bash" process you can input as a filter:

```
COMMAND=bash
```

This will show only command bash.
Man top (1) for more information, look for FILTER.

Comment: This works on `Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM)`

Answer (score 3):

Once you know the PID of the process you wish to track (through running `ps auxw |grep your_process`) run top in batch mode:

```
top -b -n 1 -p 1234 | tail -n 1
```

Where 1234 is your process PID

This approach is better for tracking. It is safer than using `grep` on a name, more straightforward and uses less resources.

Answer (score 0):

When your `top` does not know the `-p` option (`top: invalid option -- 'p'`), then you can get a similar result using the batch mode with `-b`:

```
top -b | grep java
```

Comment: Wonder why this has been downvoted?